# Dataframe Delete value from specific columns by matching specific KEY in like " .0 " and after that only " . " can be numeric and in string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Delete a value from the end and in middle
So, first, delete .0 in from the end and then remove "." from whole columns

```
id Zip              Contact
1  12345.0,67890.0  123.213.1234
2  5.567.4          1212121212.0
3  11111
4  22222.           999.999.9999,7897897897.0

print(out)

id Zip              Contact
1  12345,67890      1232131234
2  55674            1212121212
3  11111
4  22222            9999999999,7897897897
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include the code to recreate your dataframe at least.

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem by using replace function for both columns

df['Phone']=df['Phone'].replace('.','',regex=True)
df['Contact']=df['Contact'].replace('.','',regex=True)

I am not sure how to remove " .0 " from and if multiple value in cell then what should I do?

Comment: So the commas indicate multiple values, i.e., tuples? Are the values all strings? E.g., what is the type of 999.999.9999? Indeed, please include the code to create the dataframe.

Comment: Meanwhile, maybe have a look at [DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html); str.endswith; and str.replace.

Comment: data is in float, int or str so first have to convert in single formate

Comment: Is this the starting dataframe you have? `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Zip': ['12345.0,67890.0', '5.567.4', 11111, '22222.'], 'Contact': ['123.213.1234', 1212121212.0, None, '999.999.9999,7897897897.0']})`

Comment: ye, it's starting data frame I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply a function on each column:

```py
def f(ser):
    return (ser[~ser.isna()]
            .astype(str)
            .str.removesuffix(".0")
            .str.replace('\.', '', regex=True))

df[['Zip', 'Contact']] = df[['Zip', 'Contact']].apply(f)
```